# CSS: float does not apply when used through a class

Tags: css, position, css-float

I have two CSS elements (rules) which have exactly the same characteristics, but one has to be floated to the left and the other one to the right. Not to copy the same elements for the sake of just one rule, I tried to apply the floating as a class, as so:

```
<div id="content" class="fl-left"><div id="content" class="fl-right">
```

But it does not work, both divs are in the "natural flow" on the left. However, when I put the float rule inside the element, it does work.

```
#fleft { rules ... float: left; } #fright { same rules... float: right}
```

Would it, somehow, be possible to apply the floating as an "external" rule, just to apply it to the elements that need it, without copying the same element two times just with different floats?

Thank you

Comment: You're confusing ID (`#fleft`) and classes (`.fleft`)

Comment: No, I probably expressed it in a wrong way. When I have the separate fl-left class, it does not work. The #fleft was an example of when there are the two virtually same elements, used as '<div id="fleft"><div id="fright">'

But thanks for an answer. The problem actually was that I was on Node.js and it didn't restart properly, so the style did not reload.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing ID (#fl-left) and classes (.fl-left)

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#fl-left {
  float: left;
}
#fl-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="fl-left">Left</div>
<div id="fl-right">Right</div>
```